# Django-table2 and Django-filter is not filtering

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-filter, django-tables2

I'm doing exactly like the documentation, but when I type a value in the "name" field and click on Filter, the page refreshes but nothing is filtered. Follow my code.

**filter.py**

```
class ClientFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Client
        fields = ['name']
```

**views.py**

```
class RelatorioClientsView(FilterView, ExportMixin, CustomListView):
    template_name = 'relatorios/clients/geral.html'
    model = Client
    table_class = ClientTable
    context_object_name = 'all_clients'
    permission_codename = 'view_clients'
    filterset_class = ClientFilter

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(RelatorioClientsView,
                        self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        table = ClientTable(Client.objects.all())
        table.paginate(page=self.request.GET.get('page', 1), per_page=15)

        context['table'] = table
        RequestConfig(self.request).configure(table) #ordena

        return context
```

**tables.py**

```py
class ClientTable(ColumnShiftTable):
    class Meta:
        model = Client
        sequence = ('id', 'name')
        template_name = 'django_tables2/bootstrap.html'
```

**template.html**

```py
{% load render_table from django_tables2 %}
{% load bootstrap3 %}
{% if filter %}
     <form action="" method="get" class="form form-inline">
           {% bootstrap_form filter.form layout='inline' %}
           {% bootstrap_button 'filter' %}
     </form>
{% endif %}
{% render_table table' %}
```

[Here](https://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/filtering.html)
is the documentation part link for filter

Answer (score 0):

Filtered queryset is overwritten in your views.py by original queryset:

```
table = ClientTable(Client.objects.all())
```

You don't have to pass Client objects to context in views